# how add alias to .irbrc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, irb

I want add alias to my .irbrc similary like

```
alias q exit
```

(work).

But I want to run some command, for example

```
alias cleandb="DatabaseCleaner.clean"
```

(don't work).
How execute this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reopen the [kernel](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel) module. Something like the following:

```
module Kernel

   def q
     exit
   end

end
```